# Questions to the proof of Lemma 9.3 in Humphreys "Representations of Semisimple Lie algebras in the BGG Category $\mathcal{O}$"

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, category-o

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ with root system $\Phi$, Weyl group $W$ and Cartan decomposition $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h}\oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha \in \Phi} \mathfrak{g}_\alpha $. Fix a set of positive roots $\Phi^+ \subset \Phi$ and simple roots $\Delta \subset \Phi$. Then $I \subset \Delta$, defines a root system $\Phi_I \subset \Phi$ with positive roots $\Phi_I^+ \subset \Phi^+$ and a Weyl group $W_I \subset W$. Furthermore be $\mathfrak{n}_I^-=\bigoplus_{\alpha \in -\Phi_I^+}\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$.

In Humphreys "Representations of Semisimple Lie algebras in the BGG Category $\mathcal{O}$" we have the following Lemma 9.3:

Let $M \in \mathcal{O}$ have the set of weights $\Pi(M)$. The following conditions are equivalent:

1. $M$ is locally $\mathfrak{n}_I^-$-finite.
2. For all $\alpha \in I$ and $\mu \in \Pi(M)$ we have $\dim M_\mu=\dim M_{s_{\alpha}\mu}$.
3. For all $w \in W_I$ and $\mu \in \Pi(M)$ we have $\dim M_\mu=\dim M_{w\mu}$.
4. $\Pi(M)$ is stable under $W_I$.

Now I struggle with the main parts of the proof.

In "$1. \Rightarrow 2.$" he argues the following way. For $\alpha \in I$ fixed, consider the action of the subalgebra generated by $x_\alpha \in \mathfrak{g}_\alpha$ and $y_\alpha \in \mathfrak{g}_{-\alpha}$, which is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl} (2,\mathbb{C})$, on $M_\mu$. This gives a finite dimensional submodule $N$ of $M$, which is stable under $\mathfrak{h}$. Then the standard theory for finite dimensional representations of $\mathfrak{sl} (2,\mathbb{C})$ yields $2.$

Questions that arise for me:

1. Does he consider $N$ as a finite dimensional $\mathfrak{sl} (2,\mathbb{C})$-module?
2. Why is $N$ $\mathfrak{h}$-stable and why is this necessary?
3. I know how the simple $\mathfrak{sl} (2,\mathbb{C})$-modules look like but how does this imply 2. ?

In "$4. \Rightarrow 1.$" He constructed a weight $\mu'(=w_I\mu)$, such that only finitely many $\mathbb{Z}^+$-linear combinations of $-\Phi_I^+$ can be added to $\mu'$ to lie in $\Pi(M)$. Then he says that $\mu'$ is a typical weight of $M$, forcing $M$ to be locally $\mathfrak{n}_I^-$-finite.

4. How does this weight forces $M$ to be locally $\mathfrak{n}_I^-$-finite? Have the impression there is kind of standard argument used.

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) $h x_\alpha m_\mu = (\mu(h) - \alpha(h))x_\alpha m_\mu$, or something like that, and similarly for $y_\alpha$. (3) By decomposing into irreducible $\mathfrak{sl}$-submodules that intersect $M_\mu$, one sees that the dimension computation can be done for an irreducible submodule. For each such module, one knows that the dimension of the weight spaces behaves as desired. (4) The $\mathfrak n^-$-submodule of $M$ spanned by $M_{\mu'}$ is spanned by the weight spaces as you say.  There are finitely many of those and each is finite dimensional.

Comment: (My [argument](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370158/questions-to-proof-of-lemma-9-3-in-humphreys-representations-of-semisimple-lie#comment935133_370158) for (3) is a little sketchy, but I think it basically works.)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! (2) Yeah right. But why is it necessary to have $\mathfrak{h}$-stability? (4) Then the argument is that every weight of $M$ can be expressed as such a $\mu'$? Otherwise I don't see how I get it locally everywhere. My definition of locally $\mathfrak{n}_I^-$-finite is that for every $v \in M$ is $U(\mathfrak{n}_I^-)v$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: (2) To conclude that $M_\mu$ is the sum of $N_\mu$ as $N$ ranges over such submodules, and analogously for $M_{s_\alpha\mu}$.  (4) Not every weight of $M$, but every weight of $U(\mathfrak n^-)m_{\mu'}$ for $m_{\mu'} \in M_{\mu'}$.

Comment: So I still don't get how locally $\mathfrak{n}^-$ finiteness is shown. If I start with $v \in M_\lambda \subset M$ and $\lambda$ is not a weight of such a $U{(\mathfrak{n}^-})M_\mu'$, which as far as I understood you can be the case.  How does it follows that $U{(\mathfrak{n}^-})v$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: What about this: Let $v \in M_\lambda$. Then $w_I\lambda$ is by assumption a weight of $M$ and only finitely many $Z^+$-linear combinations of $\Phi_I^+$ can be added to get a weight of $M$. Thus, as $\lambda=w_I(w_I\lambda)$, only finitely many  $Z^+$-linear combinations of $\Phi_I^-$ can be added to $\lambda$ to get a weight of $M$. Hence $U(\mathfrak{n}^-)M_\lambda $ is finite dimensional, especially $U(\mathfrak{n}^-)v$.

Comment: Each $v$ lies in a sum of finitely many weight spaces, and the $U(\mathfrak n^-)$-span of each of those weight spaces is f.d., so $U(\mathfrak n^-)v$ lies in the sum of finitely many f.d. spaces.  (I don't know why you worry about $v \in M_\lambda$ with $\lambda$ not as above; $\mu$ is just an arbitrary label here, so, if you want to work with $U(\mathfrak n^-)M_\lambda$ instead of $U(\mathfrak n^-)M_\mu$, then just do the entire reasoning with $\lambda$ in place of $\mu$.)

Comment: Yeah that's why, as I did, it is enough to consider only elements from a weight space. I have choosen $\lambda$ because $\mu$ was related to $\mu'$, which was a weight Humphreys constructed. I tried to avoid double meanings etc.

Comment: Right, but this is my point:  you don’t first choose $\mu$ and then try to show that $U(\mathfrak n^-)v$ is finite for $v \in M_\lambda$; you first choose $v$, decompose into weight spaces as above, pick your favourite weight space, *call the weight $\mu$*, and *then* carry out the proof.

Comment: One point that bothers me. (3) I thought for your argumentation we need that $M_\mu, M_{s_\alpha\mu} \subset N$. Obviously $M_\mu \subset N$. But why holds$ M_{s_\alpha\mu} \subset N$?

Comment: (3) A little sketchy, as I [said](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370158#comment935136_370158). Neither one necessarily contained in $N$, but $M_\mu = \sum N_\mu$ and $M_{s_\alpha\mu} = \sum N_{s_\alpha\mu}$, over all possible $N$'s.  So we just verify it for the piece of the weight space in each individual $N$, and then sum.

Comment: Oh you are right, I'm still not very familiar with Lie algebra representations. Mmmh then I'm wondering what do you mean by "over all possible N's"? The $N$'s you get by varying the $\alpha \in I$?

Comment: You say "consider the action of … $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb C)$ on $M_\mu$.  This gives … $N$"; but actually it doesn't pin down a particular $N$.  Rather, we can decompose $M$ as a sum of *various* $N$s (due to complete reducibility of complex $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb C)$-representations).  The $N$s that occur in such a decomposition are what I am referring to as "all possible $N$s".

Comment: I took it from Humphreys and understood in the way that $N=\{m \in M \mid m=X.v \text{ with } X \in \langle x_\alpha, y_\alpha \rangle \cong \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}), v \in M_\mu \}$. Hence for me there is a particular $N$. Why it shouldn't? Furthermore what is the reason for Humphreys to fix $\alpha \in I $ and proceed as he did?

Comment: Is $M$ complete reducible as a $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ representation if it is not finite-dimensional?

Comment: Let $v \in M_\mu$ then $\mu(h_\alpha)v=h_\alpha.v=[x_\alpha,y_\alpha].v \in N$. Hence $v\in N$ and we have $M_\mu \subset N$.

Comment: Yes, all representations of $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb C)$ are completely reducible. (The f.-d. case is less interesting.)  Your reasoning for $M_\mu \subseteq N$ seems to use $\mu(h_\alpha) \ne 0$.  I guess you could use a variant $N = M_\mu + \mathfrak g_\alpha\cdot M_\mu$ if you already know $M_\mu$ is f.-d.  Anyway, I think this is enough back and forth for the comments.

Comment: https://math.berkeley.edu/~reb/courses/261/35.pdf Excercise 283 let me believe something different. But okay I will think on my own. Thanks for all your comments.

Comment: You are [right](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370158#comment936605_370158) and I am [wrong](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370158#comment936589_370158) (I was thinking of the compact-group case). Sorry! I agree that your $N = M_\mu + \mathfrak g_\alpha M_\mu$ is a better construction. Since it is f.-d., it's an $\operatorname{SU}(2)$-rep., so stable under the reflexion $s_\alpha$, so contains $s_\alpha M_\mu = M_{s_\alpha\mu}$.

Comment: I'm relieved to hear that. I'm wondering if there isn't a way to see that $M_{s_\alpha \mu}\subset N$ without considering any $SU(2)$-action. Thats the impression I got from Humphreys proofs.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370158/questions-to-the-proof-of-lemma-9-3-in-humphreys-representations-of-semisimple#comment936821_370158), I guess the point is that a suitable $x_\alpha^n M_\mu$ or $y_\alpha^n M_\mu$ (depending on $\langle\alpha, \mu\rangle$) should equal $M_{s_\alpha\mu}$.

Comment: Thats was my first idea too, but $\langle \alpha, \mu \rangle $ don't has to lie in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Do you have an example where $\langle\alpha, \mu\rangle$ doesn't lie in $\mathbb Z$?  (By the way, I also realise that there is a more serious objection than [mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370158/questions-to-the-proof-of-lemma-9-3-in-humphreys-representations-of-semisimple#comment936589_370158) to using $\mathfrak g_\alpha\cdot M_\mu$, namely, that it's not necessarily $\mathfrak g_\alpha$-stable!  We both meant $\mathcal U(\mathfrak g_\alpha)\cdot M_\mu$.)

Comment: After your doubts I went through some basic textbook and you are right- $\langle \mu, \alpha \rangle \in \mathbb{Z}$. Can be found for example in  Humphreys "Lie algebras and Representations Theory" section 7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the outstanding help of LSpice I present a version of more detailed proof of the two parts above. Do not hesitate to point out mistakes.

"$(1) \Rightarrow (2)$": Fix $\alpha \in I$ and $\mu \in \Pi(M)$. Observe that for $\mu(h_\alpha)=0$, we have $s_\alpha\mu=\mu-\langle \mu, \alpha^{\vee}\rangle \alpha = \mu - \mu(h_\alpha)\alpha=\mu$ and $(2)$ follows trivially. Hence we can assume $\mu(h_\alpha) \neq 0$.
Then by assumption and as $M\in \mathcal{O}$ the action on $M_\mu$ of the subalgebra $\mathfrak{s}_\alpha \cong \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$, generated by $x_\alpha \in \mathfrak{g}_\alpha$, $y_\alpha \in \mathfrak{g}_{-\alpha}$, produces a finite dimensional $U(\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}))$-submodule $N \subset M$.

For $v \in M_\mu$, we have that $N \ni h_\alpha.v=\mu(h_\alpha)v$. Hence $M_\mu \subset N$. For $x_\alpha,y_\alpha$ exists $n_\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_\alpha^{n_\alpha+1}.N=y_\alpha^{n_\alpha+1}.N=0.$ Define
\begin{align*}
\exp(x_\alpha)&:=\sum_{k=0}^{n_\alpha} x_\alpha^k/k! \in U(\mathfrak{sl},(2,\mathbb{C}))\\
\exp(y_\alpha)&:=\sum_{k=0}^{n_\alpha} y_\alpha^k/k! \in U(\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})),\\
s&:=\exp(x_\alpha)\exp(-y_\alpha)\exp(x_\alpha) \in U(\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}))
\end{align*}
Then as in the proof of Theorem 21.2 of Humphreys "Lie algebras and Representations Theory", we additionally have that $M_{s_\alpha\mu}=s.M_\mu \subset N$.

As $N$ is finite dimensional, $N=\bigoplus N_i$ with $N_i$ simple  $U(\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}))$-module. Observe that
\begin{align*}
h.(x_\alpha.v)&=(x_\alpha h+\alpha(h)x_\alpha).v=(\mu(h)+\alpha(h))x_\alpha.v, \\
h.(y_\alpha.v)&=(x_\alpha h-\alpha(h)x_\alpha).v=(\mu(h)-\alpha(h))y_\alpha.v,
\end{align*}
for $v \in M_\mu, h \in \mathfrak{h}$. Thus $N$ is $\mathfrak{h}$-stable and  $M_\mu=\bigoplus (N_i)_\mu$ resp. $M_{s_\alpha\mu}=\bigoplus (N_i)_{s_\alpha\mu}$ follows. But for simple $U(\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}))$-module $N_i$ we know that $\dim((N_i)_{s_\alpha\mu})=\dim((N_i)_\mu)$ and the claim follows.

"$(4) \Rightarrow (1)$": We want to show that $U(\mathfrak{n}_I^-).v$ is finite dimensional for every $v \in M$.  As $M$ is $\mathfrak{h}$-semisimple, we can assume that $v \in M_\mu$ for some $\mu \in \Pi(M)$. Then by assumption $w_I\mu \in \Pi(M)$ and only finitely many $\mathbb{Z}^+$-linear combinations of $\Phi_I^+$ can be added to get a weight of $M$.Thus, as $\mu=w_I(w_I\mu)$ and $w_I$ interchange $\Phi_I^+$ and $\Phi_I^-$, only finitely many $\mathbb{Z}^+$-linear combinations of $\Phi_I^-$ can be added to $\mu$ to lie in $\Pi(M)$. Hence $U(\mathfrak{n}_I^-)M_\mu$ is finite dimensional, especially $U(\mathfrak{n}_I^-).v$.

Comment: By the way, although it is confusing to the extent of being highly regrettable, I think that the usual notation is to use $\mathfrak u_\alpha$ for the root space and $U_\alpha$ for the root group, and then $\mathfrak g_\alpha$ for the Lie algebra of the group $G_\alpha \mathrel{:=} \langle U_\alpha, U_{-\alpha}\rangle$.

Comment: Mmmh where have you seen this? For example in Humphreys  "Representations of Semisimple Lie algebras in the BGG Category $\mathcal{O}$" it is as I used it and I consider Humphreys as an expert of this topic. I cannot remember to have ever seen $\mathfrak{u}_\alpha$ for the root space.

Comment: There's a holy trinity of reductive-group books:  [Borel](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-0941-6), [Humphreys](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4684-9443-3), and [Springer](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-8176-4840-4).  [Milne](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/algebraic-groups/48D122BAEC63C2B70304E20F34482C8F) is a recent addition to the canon.  I find as you say that all use $\mathfrak g_\alpha$ on the Lie algebra—to my astonishment, because they use $U_\alpha$ and $G_\alpha$ as I say, so $\mathfrak g_\alpha$ is not the Lie alg. of $G_\alpha$!

Comment: Alright that's consistent with what I know.

Comment: I find to my semi-relief that [Conrad, Gabber, and Prasad](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/pseudoreductive-groups/CA287151E422CA75682AE7A460008504), at least in the 1st edition, while not adopting my suggestion of using $\mathfrak u_\alpha$ for the root space, at least, as far as I can tell, only ever refer to the space in words without ever giving it a symbolic name.

Comment: Okay but  I prefer $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$, since   the u/U of $\mathfrak{u}_\alpha$ comes from unipotent which doesn't fit for me in setting of Lie algebras.